# Why was this question with score of +2 deleted by Community?

Tags: support, status-declined, deleted-questions, community-user, auto-delete

The following question was deleted by Community♦ (Roomba):

[Simulate NPDAs with DTMs using only polynomial overhead](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33067/755)

Why?  What the heck?

The help page [lists a bunch of criteria under which Roomba will delete a post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), but none of those cases apply here.  This is a question with score of +2 (2 upvotes, no downvoted), not closed or migrated.

The reason given for automatic deletion was "RemoveAbandonedQuestions".  However, according to the help page, that's only supposed to apply to questions with a score of 0 (or 1 in case of deleted owner).  The owner is not deleted, and the score is 2.

So why did Roomba delete this question?  This seems like a bug to me.  I don't think the question should have been deleted, according to the published criteria; and I wouldn't want the question to disappear, as it seems interesting.

---

Here's a screenshot for those of you who don't have 10K rep on CS.SE:

[image]

Comment: @Oded I understand you retagged this, but as Shadow Wizard said, this might be considered a bug (trolls getting good content deleted)

Comment: @Pat well, the [related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280233/vote-invalidation-script-should-undelete-questions-that-were-previously-wrongly) has been declined by Shog.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Wait, how does a [meta-tag:support] question get [meta-tag:status-declined]? "No support for you!"?

Comment: @ilm i blame Oded for retagging

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question *had* two downvotes on it as well, and was deleted when the score was 0. The downvotes were later invalidated due to some voting irregularities, which caused the score to rise back up to 2.

I've gone ahead and undeleted it.

Comment: There's no way this is the only case of this happening. Apparently an addition has to be made to the script that deals with invalidating votes!

Comment: So trolls roam SE, causing otherwise good questions to be deleted. Nice. :/